# Django, select a maximum from annotated maximums (maximum from a few fields)

Tags: django

I have a question about django annotation methods:
is it possible to calculate "maximum_discount" of these 3 particular discounts (and sort by this "maximum_discount")?

```
Product.objects\
   .annotate(
        product_discount=Max('discounts__amount'),
        category_discount=Max('category__discounts__amount'),
        brand_discount=Max('brand__discounts__amount')
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
max_discount = max(value for key, value in Product.objects\
   .annotate(  # maybe 'aggregate'?
        product_discount=Max('discounts__amount'),
        category_discount=Max('category__discounts__amount'),
        brand_discount=Max('brand__discounts__amount')
    )
)
```

Comment: Each discounts here, are GenericRelations, so I have to select discounts for products, categories, brands, and then to select maximum from these discounts, and sort by them (and even more - to apply this calculated discount to prices).

example:
Product 6 :: 5.00 :: 20.00 :: 25.00 --> 25.00

So I need to do it in a queryset..

Comment: I fear it goes far behind Django's queryset possibilities. Maybe you should try raw query.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#greatest) you can do next thing:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest
Product.objects.annotate(max_discount=Greatest('discounts__amount', 'brand__discounts__amount', 'category__discounts__amount'))
```

**But note that this appear in Django 1.9.**